# How to write a code for products page using testng in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, testng

friends I am working on products page whenever i am clicking the products page it display the page with a to z alphabeticals and range selection. Whenever i clicking on range and alphabetical A(havin 1 to no of pages) it display no of images.how to write a code for to count the no of images in that inner page and how to check if the are found or not

Comment: Can you please share URL?

Answer (score 0):

Present I am working in this project.I think this link is not open.I explain with an example.In amazon website we have no of products.suppose you click on some of product like watches in that page u have no of images.How can you write a program to count the number of images in that inner page not a web page.Like that in my project i have a products page.In that products can be displayed in alphabetical wise and also having range(20 to 50).Suppose I am clicking products page and select range 20 and my task is is there only 20 products or more than.How can I write a program by using testng in selenium